# How to extract text from unicode subtitle?

Tags: php, regex, unicode, subtitle

I have a unicode subtitle file formatted like this :

```
3
00:01:40,200 --> 00:01:43,326
english part

4
00:01:43,534 --> 00:01:44,851
خط فارسی

5
00:01:45,063 --> 00:01:48,485
complex part مخلوط

6
00:01:45,063 --> 00:01:48,485
complex part مخلوط
in 2 lines
```

How can I extract numbers as key and the text as value

```
[
   [3] => english part
   [4] => خط فارسی
   [5] => complex part مخلوط
   [6] => complex part مخلوط</br>in 2 lines
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the found numbers as indices. Better use ongoing indices and key/value pairs instead.
That said, you could go for (enable `multiline` and `verbose`, `m` and `x`):

```
^(\d+)\R
[->\d: ,]+\R
((?:.+\R?)+)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/zRm5xF/1/).

---

In `PHP` this could be

```
<?php

$text = <<<END
3
00:01:40,200 --> 00:01:43,326
english part

4
00:01:43,534 --> 00:01:44,851
خط فارسی

5
00:01:45,063 --> 00:01:48,485
complex part مخلوط

6
00:01:45,063 --> 00:01:48,485
complex part مخلوط
in 2 lines
END;

$regex = <<<END
~
    ^(?P<line>\d+)\R
    [->\d: ,]+\R
    (?P<content>(?:.+\R?)+)
~mx
END;

preg_match_all($regex, $text, $matches);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

See [**another demo on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/p789wR).